# Share mobile broadband through a Wi-Fi router with an Ethernet cable?

Tags: ethernet, wireless-networking, bridging

I have a mobile broadband modem (Huawei E220, from Spanish carrier MoVistar) connected to a Ubuntu (Natty) laptop. Internet works well with regular settings.

I want to share that connection through a Wi-Fi modem (Comtrend AR-5381u) provided by the Spanish carrier Jazztel. I also have a standard Ethernet RJ45 cable.

The problem is: the router hasn't got any 'input' Ethernet but an telephone port and 4 'output' Ethernet ports.

How can I make the router to use the Ethernet connection to create the Wi-Fi network with internet instead of the telephone connection?

I've seen an option in the router settings called Bridging, but I don't know how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer to this is that you can't do it from the router settings but I'm fairly sure you can just set up ubuntu to share it's internet connection which would make it available to all the computers on the network without doing anything to the router. You're only problem would be getting the router to direct all the traffic to your ubuntu machine instead of trying to use the built in modem.

This page might help

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing